# Improve recursive count of entries with related parent ID

Tags: c#, recursion, count

Currently my data looks somewhat like this

```
ID      PARENT ID
1       0
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       3
6       5
```

I want to count the items which are related to one parent
e.g counting for ID 1 returns 5, because

```
ID 2 has ID 1 as parent
ID 3 has ID 2 as parent, which has ID 1 as parent
ID 4 has ID 2 as parent, which has ID 1 as parent
ID 5 has ID 3 as parent, which has ID 2 as parent, which has ID 1 as parent
ID 6 has...
```

I solved this using simple recursion

```
private int Count(Entry entry)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    foreach (Entry foundEntry in AllEntries.Where(x => x.ParentID == entry.ID)) {
        cnt++;
        cnt += Count(found);
    }

    return cnt;
}

// somewhere in the code
foreach (Entry currentEntry in AllEntries.Where(x => x.ParentID == 1).ToList()) {
    cnt++;
    cnt += Count(currentEntry );
}
```

Is there any other way which doesn't use recursion? (LINQ, Stack..)

Comment: This problem does not need recursion.  You want to search the PARENT ID column of ID = 1.  Unless you are looking for all the descendants of 1 then you need recursion.  If you are looking for descendants then you need to use either recursion or the Push/Pop method.

Comment: Of course you need recursion, how you want to find out all children and grandchildren otherwise?

Comment: @jdweng I think you misread my problem, I need recursion because I want to count items based on a changing variable. Otherwise I could just use ```.Count(...)```

Comment: What does changing have to do with this question?  Either you want just the children (does not require recursion) or you want the descendants (require recursion).

Comment: Not changing the ref means that I want the first level children = no recursion. But as stated in my question, my goal requires recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could iterate through `AllEntries` and keep track of the related parents in a `HashSet<int>`:

```
private int Count(Entry entry)
{
    HashSet<int> parentIds = new HashSet<int>();
    parentIds.Add(entry.ID);

    int count = 0;
    foreach (Entry e in AllEntries.OrderBy(x => x.ParentID))
    {
        if (parentIds.Contains(e.ParentID))
        {
            count++;
            parentIds.Add(e.ID);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
int count = Count(AllEntries[0]) //where AllEntries[0] = new Entry(){ ID = 1, ParentID = 0 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "can be changed"? I guess nothing is changed between the time the method is called and the time when it returns. Please provide some sample data where my code returns the wrong answer. Or just adapt the code yourself. You should get the idea of how to solve this using iteration rather than recursion.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I didn't use the correct data for testing. Your solution works perfectly!